# Load Second UIViewController into Container on Button Click

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, uicontainerview

So here is my situation, I have a few `UIViewController`'s, they are:

1. View Controller
2. First Sector
3. Second Sector

The View Controller (1) has buttons on the left (within a `UIView`) and it has a `UIContainerView` which slides to the right (to reveal said buttons) with a gesture - this is hopefully going to be my menu (see screenshot).

The First Sector (2) I have managed to load as the default view of the ContainerView mentioned above.

I want to load the Second Sector (3) into the ContainerView when the button is clicked.

Screenshot so far:

[image: controllers]

How is it I am going to get this to load into the container?

I have tried to drag the "embed" from Presenting Segues across to the Container, however that just gives the option of `viewDidLoad` which obviously sets it as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library that already implemented all work for you. It's called [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). It's a really powerful library to present menu on the left like you want to.

Comment: I just gave this a quick test out and it works perfectly, even managed to add a couple of extra buttons and view controllers no problem. Thank you for this, i'll use this Library considering i'm early on in the project.